# How to form array of objects data to QR code with qr-image module for scan and result should shown in excel on separate cells

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, qr-code

var codeContent = {
"content": "This is sample content",
"Fields" : [{
"Field name": "Value 1",
"Field Value": "Red color"
}, {
"Field name": "Value 2",
"Field Value": "Orange color"
}]
}

```
 var qr_png = qr.image(codeContent, {
        type: 'png',
        size: 3, //4 comment
        ec_level: 'L',
        margin: 0
    });
```

Excepted Output when scanned
[image: How to format the data to separate cells like this]